# An error occurs when I try to change my display name on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, profile-page

I'd like to change my display name, but after filling in my profile, if I click on the <kbd>Save Profile</kbd> button, there's this error:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
> This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our account recovery page to get access to this
> account.